# multiple record in a single row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have post graduation degree records of students in my database. student may have only one post graduation degree, some students may have more than one post graduation degree.

```
rollno | pgdegree | score
--------------------------
0001   | 41       | 56
0002   | 42       | 78
0002   | 49       | 75
0003   | 48       | 77
```

Here roll no. **0002** is more than one time and roll no. **0001,0003** are only one time.

i want my desired output as :

```
rollno | pgdegree1 | score1 | pgdegree2 | score2
------------------------------------------------
0001   | 41        | 56     |           | 
0002   | 42        | 78     | 49        | 75
0003   | 48        | 77     |           |
```

> Note : in my database any student can have one or two post gradation only. Not more than two PG degree.

Comment: If you have exactly one or two PG, you could join the table with itself using the `rollno` and printing `pgdegree` and `score` for both the original and joined table. Contra: students with only one PG will have the same values for `pgdegree1` and `pgdegree2` respectively `score1` and `score2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution using `ROW_NUMBER()` and conditional aggregation to save some unnecessary SELECTs :

```
SELECT s.rollno,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 1 THEN s.pgdegree END) AS pgdegree1, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 1 THEN s.score    END) AS score1, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 2 THEN s.pgdegree END) AS pgdegree2, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 2 THEN s.score    END) AS score2
FROM
(
    SELECT t.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.rollno ORDER BY t.pgdegree, t.score) AS rnk
    FROM YourTable t
) s
GROUP BY s.rollno
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a self `LEFT JOIN` to add second pgdegree if available for a rollno. Do `NOT EXISTS` to only return rows with lowest pgdegree as t1.pgdegree.

```
select t1.rollno, t1.pgdegree, t1.score, t2.pgdegree, t2.score
from tablename t1
  left join tablename t2
      on t1.rollno = t2.rollno and t1.pgdegree < t2.pgdegree
where not exists (select * from tablename t3
                  where t1.rollno = t3.rollno
                    and t1.pgdegree > t3.pgdegree)
```

Comment: Your query is not giving exact result. I have 4529 distinct roll no in the table but your query results 4614 rows. The answer i have accepted giving exact records.

Comment: @DhairyaLakhera, are you perhaps having rollno/pgdegree duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a clever pivot query:

```
SELECT t.rollno,
    SUM(CASE WHEN pgdegree = (SELECT MIN(pgdegree) FROM yourTable WHERE rollno = t.rollno)
             THEN pgdegree ELSE 0 END) AS pgdegree1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN pgdegree = (SELECT MIN(pgdegree) FROM yourTable WHERE rollno = t.rollno)
             THEN score ELSE 0 END) AS score1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN pgdegree = (SELECT MAX(pgdegree) FROM yourTable WHERE rollno = t.rollno)
             THEN pgdegree ELSE 0 END) AS pgdegree2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN pgdegree = (SELECT MAX(pgdegree) FROM yourTable WHERE rollno = t.rollno)
             THEN score ELSE 0 END) AS score2
FROM yourTable t
GROUP BY t.rollno
```

**Explanation:**

The first two `CASE` statements have subqueries which will return `pgdegree` if that value happens to be the *minimum* value for that given `rollno`.  This `pgdegree` and `score` will appear as the first two columns.  Similarly, the last two `CASE` statements use the *maximum* value to generate the second two columns.

Comment: The largest university in the US has an enrollment of a little over 60K students (q.v. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_university_campuses_by_enrollment)).  Multiply this by at most 2 for the 2 degrees.  I don't consider 100K to be so large that this query should be a major problem.

Comment: I wasn't talking about 100K records:) , other people may see this as well and their tables might be different . This indeed answer this question and will probably work great.

Comment: @Abelisto Read the question: `in my database any student can have one or two post gradation only. Not more than two PG degree` ... I would not otherwise have suggested a pivot query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  rollno,
  (array_agg(pgdegree))[1] as pgdegree1,
  (array_agg(score))[1] as score1,
  (array_agg(pgdegree))[2] as pgdegree2,
  (array_agg(score))[2] as score2
from
  your_table
group by
  rollno;
```